# Thumbreader application in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, fingerprint, image-scanner

Have a question.
Is it possible to get the data from thumb-reader and give it as input to iPhone device.

What I exactly means is I will detect my finger to the thumb reader and it will store the data in any form and then I want that by any means it must send the data to iPhone.

Now my question is

1. Is it possible to scan the thumb on external device and transfer that data to iPhone?
2. If yes the how and what all class/framework am I required to look into.
3. Any similar application?
4. Can we do this without external thumbreader scanner?

And finally (non technical question) if we have to use the external device for scanning thumb then any suggestion for the device which is compatibe with iPhone?

Comments are most welcome..

Thanks for any advice in advance.....

Comment: Are you discriminating against non-thumb digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an external thumb reader, sure, it's possible, sure. However, the thumb reader would need to communicate with the iPhone either via Bluetooth or through the 30-pin connector. You might want to read up on the [External Accessory topics in the Apple Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html#section=Frameworks&topic=ExternalAccessory).

This would, of course, be dependent on the reader being able to actually communicate with an iPhone, something that may require hardware support.

The iPhone itself cannot act as a thumbprint reader.